# What is the difference between deficient, scant, scarce, meager? how to use them?

Tags: differences, synonyms

I got this this [answer](https://www.italki.com/question/119380):

> Deficient and scarce mean there is not enough of something or that
>   something is lacking. Scant and meager mean that there is not very
>   many of something, barely sufficient. That does not necessarily mean
>   that the amount is deficient, though most of the time it does. If I
>   say the desert has scant forests, that does not necessarily mean too
>   few - just that there are few of them. The four are related and the
>   meanings overlap at times, but they are not quite the same.

can anyone explain little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deficient**
Definitely not enough. For example 'The available funding is deficient by £1,000,000'

**Scant**
Just about enough, but with no spare. May also be not quite enough. For example 'The one egg and two slices of bread each was scant provision for dinner'

**Scarce**
Very rare or in short supply. For example 'Alluvial diamonds are very scarce' or 'As a result of the drought tomatoes are scarce this year'

**Meager** (or **meagre** in british spelling)
Very similar to scant but, sometimes, referring to a more persistent situation. For example 'Because of his low wages and high rent he was on meagre rations when it came to food'.

Comment: Excellent explanations and sentences-in-context except for the observation that meagre (sometimes) connotes a "more persistent situation". I think meagre is interchangeable with your sentence-in-context (egg & bread) for scant but remains, to my way of thinking, almost always usable whether a situation is persistent or not. It is just as likely to cover a fleeting and/or a one-off occurrence.

Comment: In the context of the payment of daily, weekly, monthly wages I agree that meagre is a better choice than scant.

Comment: @Peter Point Thanks for your positive comments and I agree that 'scant' and 'meagre' are interchangeable in most cases. I also agree that 'meagre' _can_ be used for fleeting occurrances, I just feel that 'scant' is less likely to be used for longer term situations. I think we're pretty close to a consensus really.